# timer countdown 5,3,1 android

Tags: android, timer

I have made a simple app about timer countdown. My code works perfectly, but the problem has come when I run this project.The first time my app counted normally, but the second time it counted 5,3,1 not 5,4,3,2,1

here's my code timer :

```
private Handler handler=new Handler();
    public static int timer;
    private OnTimeCompleteListener timeComplete=(OnTimeCompleteListener)this;
    private Runnable timerThread=new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(timer>0){
                //Time is running 
                timer--;
                timer_text.setText("Time : "+timer);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }else{
                timeComplete.onTimeFinish();

            }

            }
        };
public void startTimer(){
        handler.postDelayed(timerThread, 100);
    }
    public void stopTimer(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(timerThread);
    }
```

how to make my timer work perfectly?

Comment: Try to move your timer variable as non-static field to your timer thread runnable. Then for every start timer initialize a new runnable.

Comment: can you give me example? @IngoSchwarz

Answer (score 0):

I thought about something like this:

```
private static final int TIMER_COUNTDOWN_VALUE = 5;

private Handler handler=new Handler();
private Runnable currentTimerRunnable = null;

public void startTimer() {
    if( currentTimerRunnable == null ) {
        currentTimerRunnable = new TimerRunnable( TIMER_COUNTDOWN_VALUE );
        handler.postDelayed(currentTimerRunnable, 100);
    }
}

public void stopTimer() {
    if( currentTimerRunnable != null ) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(currentTimerRunnable);
        currentTimerRunnabel = null;
    }
}

private class TimerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int timerValue;

    private TimerRunnable(int startValue) {
        timerValue = startValue;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if( timerValue > 0) {
            timer--;
            timerListener.onTimerUpdate( timerValue );
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        } else {
            timerListener.onTimerFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but my countdown time aren't just one time, i have 3 level, 60 sec, 30 sec and 20 sec sir

Comment: So just pass 60, 30 or 20 when creating a new TimerRunnable e.g. `new TimerRunnable( 30 );`

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: The code above is the example. The code I provided you supports already different timer values (60, 30, 20).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

create CounterClass and call its start and cancle method where you want.

```
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer
        {
            public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
            {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                //restart timer you wnat
                //timer.start();
            }

//          @SuppressLint("NewApi");
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                String hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
//              System.out.println(hms);
                tvTime.setText(hms);
            }

        }
```

create object of CounterClass and call it's method as discribe

```
timer = new CounterClass(26000, 1000);//for 26 second like,26,25....1,0.
timer.start()//where you need.
timer.cancle()//where you need.
```